# Ranking data that have the same values

Tags: r

I have a large data set including a column of counts for different genetic markers. I want to generate an overall ranking that takes into account the count number regardless of the genetic marker. For instance if 2 or more genetic markers all have a count of 5 they should all have the same rank number and I want the rank numbers to be displayed in a separate column. I have this dataframe;

```
SNP    count
a1      26
a2      18
a3      16
a4      15
a5      14
a6      14
a7      14
a8      15
a9      13
a10     12
a11     12
a12     11
a13     10
a14     9
a15     8
```

I want the output to be:

```
SNP    count   rank
a1      26    1
a2      18    2
a3      16    3
a4      15    4
a8      15    4
a5      14    5
a6      14    5
a7      14    5
a9      13    7
a10     12    8
a11     12    8
a12     11    9
a13     10    10
a14     9     11
a15     8     12
```

Note that SNPs a4 and a8 are the same, a5, a6 a7 have equal count values and also a10 and a11. I've tried

```
 transform(df, x= ave(count,FUN=function(x) order(x,decreasing=T)))
```

but it's not want I want

Comment: a4 and a8 have the same count but different ranks in your desired output..? Anyway, there's data.table::frank and dplyr::dense_rank that might be useful if you do want rank.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake a4 and a8 should both be ranked 4

Comment: If that is the case, can you edit your question and i will remove my incorrect answer

Comment: Emil rleid works all I have to do is sort the count column beforehand.

Comment: @Emil You can edit to `setDT(df)[order(-count), rank := rleid(count)]` (sorts the data temporarily just to construct the counter)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the `rleid` function from the `data.table` package.

```
data.table::rleid(df$count)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  5  5  6  7  8  8  9 10 11 12
```

`df` is obtained like so:

```
df <- read.table(text ="SNP    count
a1      26
                 a2      18
                 a3      16
                 a4      15
                 a5      14
                 a6      14
                 a7      14
                 a8      15
                 a9      13
                 a10     12
                 a11     12
                 a12     11
                 a13     10
                 a14     9
                 a15     8", 
                 stringsAsFactors =FALSE, 
                 header = TRUE)
```

And for thoroughness:

```
df$rank <- data.table::rleid(df$count)

df
   SNP count rank
1   a1    26    1
2   a2    18    2
3   a3    16    3
4   a4    15    4
5   a5    14    5
6   a6    14    5
7   a7    14    5
8   a8    15    6
9   a9    13    7
10 a10    12    8
11 a11    12    8
12 a12    11    9
13 a13    10   10
14 a14     9   11
15 a15     8   12
```

## Edit:

Thanks to @Frank, a better solution would be to sort the data frame by count before applying `rleid`:

```
setDT(df)[order(-count), rank := rleid(count)]
```

Which gives:

```
df
     SNP count rank
  1:  a1    26    1
  2:  a2    18    2
  3:  a3    16    3
  4:  a4    15    4
  5:  a5    14    5
  6:  a6    14    5
  7:  a7    14    5
  8:  a8    15    4
  9:  a9    13    6
 10: a10    12    7
 11: a11    12    7
 12: a12    11    8
 13: a13    10    9
 14: a14     9   10
 15: a15     8   11
```